# get an object out of a function to use in a field with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to get the position object out of the `getLocation` function to use in the `MapView` `initialRegion` property. Is there a way to do this? The current result is `Type '() => Position'` is not assignable to type `'number'`. Thanks!

```
getLocation(): Position {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        return position;
      },
    );
    return new Position();
  }  

render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: this.getLocation.coords.latitude *ERROR*,
          longitude: this.getLocation.coords.longitude *ERROR*,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0222,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0201,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: You have to call the `this.getLocation` function. Also consider using state instead for storing the location as you can't return value from callback function.

Comment: Where are you trying to assign to a number ??

Comment: @fastAsTortoise What do you mean where? Im trying to get a value out of position, which is returned by the getLocation function.